# Matrices and Polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Suppose we have two $n \times n$ matrices, $A,B$ and there is a polynomial, $p(x) \in \mathbb {F}[x]$ such that $p(A) = B$. How do we show that there exists another polynomial $r(x) \in \mathbb {F}[x]$ with degree at most $n$ such that $r(A) = B$?

I was thinking that of using the remainder theorem, but I don't know if it's valid for matrices.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathbb{F}[A]$ denote the ring adjoining $A$ to $\mathbb{F}$.  Since there is a polynomial $p$ with $p(A)=B$, we know that $B\in\mathbb{F}[A]$.  Furthermore, since $I,A,A^2,\dots,A^{n-1}$ span $\mathbb{F}[A]$ (say, due to the Cayley-Hamilton theorem), there is some linear combination of them which equal $B$, and so there is a polynomial $r$ with $r(A)=B$ of degree at most $n-1$.

Alternatively, let $q$ be the minimal polynomial of $A$, which has degree at most $n$, and then let $r$ be the remainder after dividing $p$ by $q$, so that $p(x)=h(x)q(x)+r(x)$.  Substituting $A$ will result in a valid equation (since powers of $A$ commute with each other -- in other words substitution is a ring homomorphism), so $p(A)=h(A)q(A)+r(A)$ means $p(A)=r(A)$ since $q(A)=0$.  This gives $r(A)=B$ since $p(A)=B$.

Comment: Amazing...I forgot about dividing by the minimal polynomial. This was an important step. Thanks.